# Why did this Taras Shevchenko poem feature David successfully deceiving Nathan the Prophet?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, taras-shevchenko, the-complete-kobzar

The poem *Czars (Kings)* by Taras Shevchenko includes a retelling of the story of David and Bathsheba (2 Samuel 11 in the Bible). One interesting feature of retelling is that Shevchenko's account includes David successfully deceiving Nathan the Prophet:

> The king simply killed [Uriah]
> He fooled old Nathan with a psalm...

In the Biblical account, Nathan was the one that confronted David about the incident.

What was the reason for this particular detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the poem *Tsars* or ("Kings"), Shevchenko is taking a satirical look at royal courts in general, presenting killing, debauchery, and adultery as being typical of their behaviour, and so allowing him to obliquely attack tsarism in particular.

The first example he presents is that of King David of Israel. One of the greatest kings of the Bible, he nonetheless committed adultery with Bathsheba the wife of Uriel the Hittite, and maneuvered Uriel to be killed (thus committing murder in some degree) to take Bathsheba as his wife. From [Andrusyshen's translation](https://archive.org/details/poeticalworksoft0000unse_c0m0), Shevchenko describes the events as:

> Meanwhile Uriah slept; the poor dear fellow 
> Never suspected what was happening 
> In secret in his household — that the king 
> Had stolen from his home, not gold or silver 
> But the more precious treasure of his wife. 
> And that the husband might not know his loss, 
> The king just had him killed, and there’s an end! ...

What were the consequences of the king's conduct? David wrote one of the penitential psalms, [Psalm 51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_51), in response to Nathan criticising him, and the child who was born as a result of the adultery was killed by god. Following this:

> David comforted his wife Bathsheba. He had intercourse with her, and
> she bore a son, whom David named Solomon.

(2 Samuel 12:24-25).

So for David there were basically no consequences; a king can do exactly as he wants. Shevchenko further underlines the emptiness of David's response by saying that the tears he shed in public were "mendacious", and the psalm he was not even  sincere, simply words to placate Nathan and the people:

> Then the king shed a few mendacious tears 
> Before the people, wrote a brand-new psalm 
> To pull the wool over old Nathan’s  eyes, 
> And happy once again, and drunk again, 
> He lavished his attentions on the lady.